# Changing CSS "left" property in javascript not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to change the position of a `div` in javascript, here is my code

```
document.getElementById("big").style.left = "-310";
```

But this isn't working in *IE*, Help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add unit to your value.

Like *pixels* :

```
document.getElementById("big").style.left="-310px";
```

Comment: worked, thanks. Is adding "px" the proper syntax or is it just used for IE?

Comment: yes, I will mark it, have to wait for some time for it

Comment: It is just a unit, like em or percentages and it is used in all browsers.

Comment: You should always add a unit, unless the value is 0. If 0 is nothing, why specify a unit for how much nothing you have? :)